# Problema con paperclip despues de inner join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

Tengo 2 tablas (***members*** y ***pics***), y acabo de hacer un **`inner join`** y ahora cuando mando a llamar a la imagen en la vista ya no me manda el url de la imagen.

Antes del **`join`** mostraba así los datos.

```
%p=pic.member.username
=image_tag pic.image.url(:thumb)
```

... y después del **`join`** las muestro así.

```
%p=pic.username
=image_tag ?
```

... y en la imagen no entiendo componerla, porque si la pongo como el ejemplo de antes, me hace muchas consultas.

¿Cómo obtener el *url* de la imagen después del **`join`**?

Comment: Podrías poner el inner join que estás haciendo?

Answer (score 0):

Como dice hcarreras, sería conveniente ver como haces el inner join.

Si es con un scope y tienes 'image' como un model distinto (no como un atributo de los model 'member' y 'pics') tienes que hacer un include. Por ejemplo:

```
# image.rb
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :title, :file
   has_attached_file :file, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
end
```

Entonces tu scope sería algo así:

```
Member.joins(:pics).include(:images)
```

Por favor, pruébalo y comentas si te funciona así.